# Execution failed for task ':permission_handler_android:extractReleaseAnnotations'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

## **Trying To Execute Flutter Build Im Getting This Error : **

`/Users/mac/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color build apk

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
/Users/mac/Desktop/Navigui-project/user-app/build/permission_handler_android/tmp/kotlin-classes/release does not exist

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':permission_handler_android:extractReleaseAnnotations'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction
> Internal error: unexpected lint return value -1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           24.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1`

## **Here Is My Pub Spec.yml

## **

```
name: booking_system_flutter
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 10.10.1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # COMMON
  nb_utils: ^6.1.0
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
  html: ^0.15.4
  http: ^1.1.0
  intl: ^0.18.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.14

  # FIREBASE
  firebase_core: ^2.22.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.4
  firebase_auth: ^4.14.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.5.1
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.3.4
  cloud_firestore: ^4.13.1

  # PUSH NOTIFICATION
  onesignal_flutter: ^5.0.4

  # STATE MANAGEMENT
  mobx: ^2.2.1
  flutter_mobx: ^2.2.0

  # ICON
  flutter_vector_icons: ^2.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9

  # IMAGE
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  lottie: ^2.7.0

  # OTHER
  country_picker: ^2.0.22
  flutter_custom_tabs: ^1.2.1
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
  firebase_pagination: ^3.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.4.2

  # SOCIAL LOGIN
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.6
  the_apple_sign_in: ^1.1.1

  # PAYMENT GATEWAYS
  phonepe_payment_sdk: ^1.0.3
  crypto: 3.0.3
  qr_flutter: 4.0.0 #required for in pix_flutter
  pix_flutter: ^2.2.0
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.5
  flutterwave_standard: ^1.0.8
  flutter_stripe: ^9.4.0
  cinetpay: ^1.0.7
  flutter_paypal_checkout:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Raj-GMITS/flutter_paypal_checkout.git
      ref: main
      
  flutter_paystack:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Raj-GMITS/flutter_paystack.git
      ref: master    

  # MAP
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.0
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  geocoding: ^2.1.1

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  mobx_codegen: ^2.4.0
  #flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/
    - assets/flag/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/upi_payment/
    - assets/lottie/
```

i tried compilersdk 33 not working